# $k$-selections of elements from a string of $n$, no two selections adjacent

Tags: combinatorics

Problem: A bookshelf contains $n$ books. We choose $k$ books such that the selected set does not contain any two books that were sitting next each other in the shelf. Calculate the number of all such $k$-selections of books.

I know the answer – it's ${n-k+1}\choose{k}$. But I completely do not understand how the answer is obtained. The solution guide suggest to think about this as about a problem with sequences of length $n$: 1 symbolize that a book is chosen and 0 if a book is not chosen.

Could you please help me understanding how to solve this problem step by step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning that yields $\binom{n-k+1}k$ selections is to add the $k$ selected books into the $n-k+1$ spaces between and around the $n-k$ non-selected books, with at most one book in each space; a bijection exists between these arrangements and the selections in the original problem.

This approach is sometimes known as [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) – the stars here are the non-selected books and the bars are the selected books.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks!